# OpenCL and Mobility Radeon x2300

Tags: opencl, ati

I have a Samsung r60+ laptop with an AMD Mobility Radeon x2300. 
Can I use it for OpenCL development?
I have installed the latest AMD SDK, but I only see the CPU compute device.

I am using Linux, but I am able to use Windows if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that AMD currently supports OpenCL for the mobility x2300. This [source](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/pages/DriverCompatibility.aspx) shows all the OpenCL devices that are supported by AMD OpenCL.

You could always write code for your CPU now, and then use the same kernel to operate on the GPU, when you get a supported device.  But note that you probably won't get optimal performance on the GPU at first.